# AS3 Video Playback with FLVPlayback

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using the code below to load some data from an .xml file.
I am preloading all data (Audio Paths, Video Paths including a video from xml.

When everything is loaded complete i am loading the video in Frame 2 on FLVPlayback 2.5 with this code:

```
videoPlayer.source = videofile;
```

The problem is that the video shows a white screen for 3-4 seconds and then starts play.
At some other pc's it plays normaly when the loading ends.

My Code:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;


stop();
//******************************************************
// XML Loader
//******************************************************
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
//myLoader.load(new URLRequest("myxml.php"));
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("myxml.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void{

    var myXml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    parseXML(myXml); 
}


//******************************************************
// Extract XML value and fill up variables
//******************************************************
var thename:XML;
var soundpath:XML;
var theage:XML;
var theplace:XML;
var everyday:XML;
var youwill:XML;
var pic1:XML;
var pic2:XML;
var pic3:XML;
var videofile:XML;

var assetsList:Array;
//-----------------------------
var sound:Sound;
var soundChannel:SoundChannel;

//-----------------------------

function parseXML(xml:XML):void{

    thename = xml.paths.thename[0];
    soundpath = xml.paths.soundpath[0];
    theage = xml.paths.theage[0];
    theplace = xml.paths.theplace[0];
    everyday = xml.paths.everyday[0];
    youwill = xml.paths.youwill[0];
    pic1 = xml.paths.pic1[0];
    pic2 = xml.paths.pic2[0];
    pic3 = xml.paths.pic3[0];
    videofile = xml.paths.videofile[0];

    txtThename.text = thename;
    txtSoundpath.text = soundpath;
    txtTheage.text = theage;
    txtTheplace.text = theplace;
    txtEveryday.text = everyday;
    txtYouwill.text = youwill;
    txtPic1.text = pic1;
    txtPic2.text = pic2;
    txtPic3.text = pic3;
    txtVideofile.text = videofile;

    assetsList = [soundpath,theage,theplace,everyday,youwill,pic1,pic2,pic3,videofile];
    preloadAssets();
}
//******************************************************
// preloaded assets
//******************************************************
var assetsLoader:URLLoader 
var assetsCtr:Number=0;

function preloadAssets():void{

    assetsLoader = new URLLoader ();
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(assetsList[assetsCtr]); 
    assetsLoader.load(urlRequest);

    assetsLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, assetLoadedHanlder);
    assetsLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, assetProgressHandler);

}

function assetProgressHandler(evt:ProgressEvent):void{
    var bl:uint = evt.bytesLoaded;
    var bt:uint = evt.bytesTotal;
    var perEachAssets = 1/assetsList.length;

    var assetsBlLoaded = ((bl / bt)*perEachAssets)+((assetsCtr)/assetsList.length*100)/100;
    var _percentLoaded = Math.floor(assetsBlLoaded*100);

    progBar.setProgress(_percentLoaded,100)
    //trace("_percentLoaded:",_percentLoaded)

}
function assetLoadedHanlder(evt:Event):void{

    assetsCtr+=1;
    if(assetsCtr<assetsList.length){
        //trace("preloading:"+assetsList[assetsCtr])
        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(assetsList[assetsCtr]); 
        assetsLoader.load(urlRequest);

    }else{
        //trace("done!")
        assetsLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, assetLoadedHanlder);
        assetsLoader.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, assetProgressHandler);
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding the component directly to the stage you might want to try creating and adding it with ActionScript.

By doing this you can instantiate the FLVPlayback instance before you need to show it, rather than having to wait until you hit frame 2 on your timeline.

I can't guarantee it will fix your problem but it's worth a go.

```
var _videoFLV:FLVPlayback;
_videoFLV = new FLVPlayback();
_videoFLV.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
_videoFLV.autoPlay = false;
_videoFLV.autoRewind = true;
_videoFLV.isLive = false;
_videoFLV.skin = null;      
_videoFLV.bufferTime = .1;
_videoFLV.width = 320;
_videoFLV.height = 240;
_videoFLV.source = videofile;
_videoFLV.stop();
_videoFLV.x = 240;
_videoFLV.y = 240;
addChild(_videoFLV);
```

Comment: I gots this error: Type was not found or was not a compile-sonstant:FLVPlayback

Comment: Make sure there is a FLVPlayback2.5 component in your library. If that doesn't fix it you can import the class with import fl.video.FLVPlayback;

Comment: i already did it.. Thank you. But it stills to see a little white screen after the loader completes..

Comment: If this is happening on just one PC it could be an issue with the PC.

Comment: No this is happening to a lot of pc's! I have a white screen for some seconds and then the video starting play.